# Hiding button until a radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function that hides & disables the submit button until a radio button is checked. Currently this is what I have and I could use a hand here.

HTML for radio buttons:

```
<label class="radioChoice"> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="lei"> lei<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="rosary"> rosary<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="poi"> poi<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="hula"> hula<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="crea"> crea<br>
</label>
<input class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" id="go-button" type="submit" value="Next Question">
```

JQuery event listener:

```
// Listen to radio button - hide submit button when none selected  
$('.radioChoice').on('click', '#go-button', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('input').find('.submit-btn').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

I've also tried using this technique but without success.

```
if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').size <= 0) {
    $('#go-button').addClass('hidden').prop('disabled', true);
} else {
    $('#go-button').removeClass('hidden').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use css and the `:checked` pseudo class.

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/745fb45w/). If you want to know more about `:checked` read [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/).

Remember that you have to put the checkbox and the submit in the same parent in order to use `~`.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
.submit-btn {
  display: none;
}

.choiceInput:checked ~ .submit-btn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="radioChoice">
  <input class="choiceInput" type="radio" name="answer" value="lei"> lei
  <br>
  <input class="choiceInput" type="radio" name="answer" value="rosary"> rosary
  <br>
  <input class="choiceInput" type="radio" name="answer" value="poi"> poi
  <br>
  <input class="choiceInput" type="radio" name="answer" value="hula"> hula
  <br>
  <input class="choiceInput" type="radio" name="answer" value="crea"> crea
  <br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" id="go-button" type="submit" value="Next Question">
</label>
```

Comment: This won't disable it, though. It just hides it. Anyone knowing two bits of code will be able to bypass this without skipping a beat. To 100% be able to disable the button until the click on an input, you'll have to dynamically create the input based on a callback from an ajax-call server-side. However, using jQuery can do this (again, this is just a minor obstacle, nothing that will prevent anyone that really wants to clicking the button).

Comment: Yep also jquery can be easy to bypass, you should build a server-side check

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (I added a .hidden-class as well, that can be used or not, doesn't really matter):

```js
// Listen to radio button - hide submit button when none selected  
$('.radioChoice input[type=radio]').click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
 $('#go-button').prop('disabled',false).removeClass('hidden');
}
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radioChoice"> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="lei"> lei<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="rosary"> rosary<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="poi"> poi<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="hula"> hula<br> 
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="crea"> crea<br>
</label>
<input class="btn btn-primary submit-btn hidden" id="go-button" type="submit" value="Next Question">
```